# HASKELL : handling NULL value in database query with Maybe (or other ...)

Tags: haskell

I have this query in SQL used by my Haskell code:

```
let name = "A    20"
let qry_head_WDS = "select DNUM from WDS where DISC = ?" :: Query
putStrLn "before query WDS"
bd_rows_WDS <- query conn qry_head_WDS (Only (name::String))
putStrLn "after query WDS"

forM_ bd_rows_WDS $ \(Only a) ->
  putStrLn $  Text.unpack a
```

works well if there is no NULL values in a database, but if NULL value
for field N°BD i got this exception at runtime:

```
before query WDS
*** Exception: UnexpectedNull {errSQLType = "String", errHaskellType =
"Text", errFieldName = "DNUM", errMessage = "unexpected null in table
WDS of database sidonie"}
*Main>
```

Can you help me to handle NULL values in the
field N°BD

Comment: Perhaps you should mention which one of the several DB access packages you are using. I'm not familiar with any of those, but it could be useful to others, I think.

Comment: it is mysql-simple

Answer (score 1):

this solution came first from the Haskell-cafe mailing list:

```
forM_ bd_rows_WDS $ \(Only x) ->
  case x of
    Nothing -> putStrLn ("x =" ++ "NULL")
    Just x -> putStrLn ("x =" ++ Text.unpack x)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `putStrLn $ "x =" ++ maybe "NULL" Text.unpack x`. The key is that `x` is a `Maybe Text` in this case, while your earler code forced it to `Text` due to the `Text.unpack` call.